# How to prove this sequence is null?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, fibonacci-numbers

I am working on the fibonacci numbers series using the ratio. To prove convergence I want to show that the sequence of the series is going to 0. And then according to the Leibniz criterion the series converge.

$a_k = a_{k-1} + a_{k-2}$

$$\sum^{\infty}_{k = 1}(\frac{a_k}{a_{k-1}} + \frac{(-1)^k}{a_ka_{k-1}})$$

How can I factor out the alternating term and more precisely show that it is monotonically decreasing null sequence.

I have thought of :

$$\sum^{\infty}_{k = 1}(\frac{a_k}{a_{k-1}} + \frac{(-1)^k}{a_ka_{k-1}}) \leq \sum^{\infty}_{k = 1}(\frac{a_k}{a_{k-1}}) + \sum^{\infty}_{k = 1}((-1)^k\frac{1}{a_ka_{k-1}})$$

but not sure if that would help me.

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{a_k}{a_{k-1}} = \dfrac{a_{k-1} + a_{k-2}}{a_{k-1}} = 1 + \dfrac{a_{k-2}}{a_{k-1}}\to 1$ as $k\to\infty$

Comment: could you please make use of LaTeX and elaborate on your thoughts?

Comment: Thank for the formatting Micahwood. The point I am making is that the alternating term will be unimportant as k gets large since the inverse term will vanish. BUT you are then left with the ratio which can easily be shown to be AT LEAST 1 or generally greater than 1 for all k. Hence the sum must diverge

Answer (score 1):

Let $$u_k = \frac{a_k}{a_{k-1}} + \frac{(-1)^k}{a_ka_{k-1}} = \frac {{a_k}^2 + (-1)^k} {a_k a_{k-1}} = \frac {a_{k + 1} a_{k - 1}} {a_k a_{k-1}} = \frac {a_{k + 1}} {a_k}.$$ The sum you're inquiring is $$\sum u_k = \sum \frac {a_{k + 1}} {a_k}.$$